# Creating Multiple Jlabels and JTextFields in a less redundant way?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, user-interface, jlabel

Anyone familiar with java Gui - swing package ...and knowing how to create multiple swing objects like "jlabels and jtextfields" in a loop of some kind that way you don't have to redundantly set each one separately? ...ANYONE???

For example - I have to create 60 Textfields and 11 Jlabels and etc.
I want to (if possible) not have to create each one separately like so

```
JLabel jlblName = new JLabel("first one"); 
JLabel jlblName = new JLabel("first two");
JLabel jlblName = new JLabel("first three");
//etc...
```

If possible I would like to also find a way to set the bounds and add the labels to the panel in a shorter way too.

I have tried different ways to achieve this - using arrays and creating get methods and still no luck .___.

PLEASE HELP ME IF YOU CAN

Below is an example of what I wrote so far...however even if it did work it doesn't seem that practical for serval reasons.
..also im not ever sure why it doesn't work.

```
public class prospectVer2
{
private static int l = 59; //, t = 20, c=11;

public static String getInfo(int b)
{
int a=b;
String [] lah = new String [prospectVer2.l];
lah [0]= "a";
lah [1]= "b";
lah [2]= "c";
lah [3]= "d";
lah [4]= "e";
lah [5]= "f";
lah [6]= "g";
lah [7]= "e";
lah [8]= "f";
lah [9]= "g";
lah [10]= "h";
lah [11]= "i";
lah [12]= "j";
lah [13]= "k";
lah [14]= "l";
lah [15]= "m";
lah [16]= "n";
lah [17]= "o";
lah [18]= "p";
lah [19]= "q";
lah [21]= "r";
lah [22]= "s";
lah [23]= "t";
lah [24]= "u";
lah [25]= "v";
lah [26]= "w";
lah [27]= "x";
lah [28]= "y";
lah [29]= "z";
lah [30]= "aa";
lah [31]= "bb";
lah [32]= "cc  ";
lah [33]= "  dd";
lah [34]= "  ee";
lah [35]= " ff ";
lah [36]= " gg ";
lah [37]= " hh ";
lah [38]= " ii ";
lah [39]= "jj";
lah [40]= "kk";
lah [41]= "ll";
lah [42]= "mm";
lah [43]= "nn";
lah [44]= "oo";
lah [45]= "pp";
lah [46]= "qq";
lah [47]= "rr";
lah [48]= "ss";
lah [49]= "tt";
lah [50]= "uu";
lah [51]= "vv";
lah [52]= "ww";
lah [53]= "xx";
lah [54]= "yy";
lah [55]= "zz";
lah [55]= "aaa";
lah [56]= "bbb";
lah [57]= "ccc";
lah [58]= "ddd";
lah [59]= "eee";
String infos= lah[a];
return infos;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
  // Declare variables - arrays

  // Create Frame and Panel - set size -
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Prospect Assignment");
  frame.setSize(700, 900);
  JPanel mypanel = new JPanel();

  JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[prospectVer2.l];

  // Create labels (60) - for loop - 
  for (int i=0; i<labels.length; i++)
    {
      labels[i] = new JLabel(prospectVer2.getInfo(i));
      mypanel.add(labels[i]);
      labels[i].setBounds(i*10+245,i*10+210,120,20);
    }

 // extra functions for gui
  frame.add(mypanel);
  mypanel.setLayout(null);
  frame.setVisible(true);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }
```

BTW I have to replicate this site using javas Swing package
https://cunycitytech.askadmissions.net/emtinterestpage.aspx?ip=prospect
THANK YOU!

Answer (score 4):

The issue will be obvious if you try start your code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 59
  at prospectVer2.getInfo(prospectVer2.java:70)
  at prospectVer2.main(prospectVer2.java:87)
```

In your code you have `private static int l = 59; //, t = 20, c=11;` and `l` is used to specify length array. In `java` array starts from `0` index so it means last accessible array index in your case should be `58`, but you try `lah[59] = "eee";`. This is reason why your code doesn't work.

You can use one of next solutions:

- increase `l`: `private static int l = 60;`;
- or remove access to `59`th index (`lah[59] = "eee";`).

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question

> how to create multiple swing objects like "jlabels and jtextfields"

You could use simple methods like:

```
JLabel getLabel(String labelText) {

    JLabel label = new JLabel(labelText);
    //do additional needed setting like font, alignment etc. 
    return label;
}
```